# How to only KEEP almost similar records in cognos

Tags: cognos-11

You're right!

This is what we are trying to achieve:
For each OrderID, Keep ONLY those OrderIDs where where their ColumnD has at least 2 SAME consecutive values AND where ColumnC has at least 2 same value in it.
So for example we would be keeping the first 2 rows of OrderID 101
So for example we would be keeping the 3 rows of OrderID 104
So for example we would be keeping the 2 rows of OrderID 305
The rest we don't want to see in the report!

Here is an image that might help explain what we want to achieve.

| OrderID | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 159 | 10 | 18$ |
| 101 | 132 | 10 | 18$ |
| 101 | 147 | 22 | 18$ |
| 102 | 111 | 12 | 55$ |
| 103 | 130 | 10 | 18$ |
| 104 | 123 | 381 | 75$ |
| 104 | 456 | 381 | 75$ |
| 104 | 789 | 381 | 75$ |
| 305 | 555 | 101 | 37$ |
| 305 | 652 | 101 | 37$ |

Comment: One of the most important rules of troubleshooting is this: if you don't know what to do, do nothing.  Another important rule is understand the problem.
How do you know you want to get rid of them?  Why do they exist?

You say this is in the report.  What is the data in the data base like?  What is the query that generated these results?  How do you know that the query isn't wrong?  How do you know that the query isn't right?

Comment: Based on the table i provided, is it enough information to understand the goal we wat to achieve and is this possible to do  ?